# SQLBase varchar col to long varchar col

Tags: sql, sqlbase

I have a SQLBase-Database where I have to modify a VARCHAR column to a LONG VARCHAR column.

As it is not possible to modfiy a datatype in sqlbase I want to create a temp column, switch the data from the varchar column to the temp column, delete the varchar column and rename the temp column.

Here are my SQLStatements:

```
ALTER TABLE NetworkShares ADD TEMP LONG VARCHAR;
UPDATE NetworkShares SET TEMP = Passwort;
ALTER TABLE NetworkShares DROP Passwort;
ALTER TABLE NetworkShares RENAME TEMP Passwort;
```

But with my code I get this errormessage:

```
Error: 01602 TYP MBB Long must be set to bind variable
```

Any ideas how I can solve my problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create table TMP_NetworkShares(
    <define all columns here as per NetworkShares>,
    PASSWORT long varchar not null
) pctfree 10;

insert into TMP_NetworkShares(
    <define all columns here as per NetworkShares>,
    PASSWORT ) select
    <define all columns here as per NetworkShares>,
    PASSWORT
        from NetworkShares;

drop table NetworkShares;

alter table TMP_NetworkShares rename table NetworkShares;

grant all on NetworkShares to PUBLIC;
```